# Counting regex pattern matches in one line using sed or grep?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, counting

I want to count the number of matches there is on one single line (or all lines as there always will be only one line).

I want to count not just one match per line as in

```
echo "123 123 123" | grep -c -E "123" # Result: 1
```

Better example:

```
echo "1 1 2 2 2 5" | grep -c -E '([^ ])( \1){1}' # Result: 1, expected: 2 or 3
```

Comment: is the data always space-separated?

Comment: There will always only be "one data" because maybe i want to match `123 123` 3 (or 2) times in `123 123 123 123`

Comment: +1 for the question, -1 for the bizarre regex example

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use `grep -o` then pipe through `wc -l`:

```
$ echo "123 123 123" | grep -o 123 | wc -l
3
```

Comment: My version of grep doesn't know what `-o` is :(

Comment: You need to ask Father Christmas for a new grep this year. :)

Comment: @manojlds, do you have `egrep`?  Same thing would work w/ `egrep`

Comment: @Mike Pennington - thanks, `egrep` says the same. I am on Windows now, so i think it's expected.

Comment: @Tylio - that's not surprising, look at your regex. It's asking for 0 or more instances of anything other than a space, followed by a space, followed by the first thing you matched again. Note: **0 or more**. There are indeed five such matches in your string (assuming you don't rewind after each match). They are: 1) `"1 1"` (bytes 1-3), 2) `" "` (i.e. zero instances of something that isn't a space, followed by a space, followed by the same zero instances again - byte 4), 3) `"2 2"` (bytes 5-7), 4) `" "` (byte 8) and finally 5) `" "` (byte 10). Phew!

Comment: (Run it without the pipe to `wc -l` at the end and you'll see them.)

Comment: What still results in 2? Your grep -E example, or my answer to your question? (I get 5 from the former, 3 from the latter.)

Comment: This: `echo "1 1 2 2 2 5" | grep -o -E '([^ ])( \1){1}' | wc -l`

Comment: As far as I know, `grep -o` won't rewind on finding a match, so this will only match "1 1" (bytes 1-3) and "2 2" (bytes 5-7). It won't match bytes 7-9 ("2 2") because by the time it comes to consider bytes 8 onwards it's already consumed bytes 1-7 in the previous two matches.

Comment: Why does echo "1 1 2 2 2 5" | grep -o 2 | wc -l which gives 3 not meet your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe below:

```
echo "123 123 123" | sed "s/123 /123\n/g" | wc -l
```

( maybe ugly, but my bash fu is not that great )

Comment: @Tyilo - what did you try? I am getting 3 for the above input

Comment: Copy and pasted your code, but i remember now that my sed doesn't support `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should convert spaces to newlines first:

```
$ echo "1 1 2 2 2 5" | tr ' ' $'\n' | grep -c 2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use awk?
You could use `awk '{print gsub(your_regex,"&")}'`
to print the number of matches on each line, or 
`awk '{c+=gsub(your_regex,"&")}END{print c}'`
to print the total number of matches. Note that relative speed may vary depending on which awk implementation is used, and which input is given.

Comment: Another way by gawk is `gawk -v FPAT=your_regex '{print NF}'` or `gawk -v FPAT=your_regex '{c+=NF}END{print c}'`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n -e ':a' -e 's/123//p' -e 'ta' file | sed -n '$='
```

GNU sed could be written:

```
sed -n ':;s/123//p;t' file | sed -n '$='
```

Comment: The first script does't work by GNU sed 4.2.2: "sed: can't find label for jump to `a'". It seems to work better, if you replace `:ta` by `:a`. The scripts seems to require newline in the end of intput. Besides, the script outputs nothing, if no matches are found. Test: `printf 123 | sed -n ':;s/123//p;t' | sed -n '$='` outputs nothing.