# SED: Number of returned lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

To a file jungle.txt with following text ...

```
A lion sleeps in the jungle
A lion sleeps tonight
A tiger awakens in the swamp
The parrot observes
Wimoweh, wimoweh, wimoweh, wimoweh
```

... one could perform GREP search ...

```
$ grep lion jungle.txt
```

... or SED search ...

```
$ sed "/lion/p" jungle.txt
```

... to find occurences of a pattern ("lion" in this case).

Is there some easy way to get a number of returned lines? Or at least to know that there was more than 1 found? As always, I've googled a lot first, but surprisingly found no answer.

Thanks!

Comment: `wc -l` to get number of lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181324/counting-regex-pattern-matches-in-one-line-using-sed-or-grep

Comment: @John1024: That is the exact replication of my situation. Thank you!

Comment: `grep -c lion jungle.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the grep command output to `wc- l` command to count the number of returned lines,

```
$ grep 'lion' file | wc -l
2
```

From `wc --help`

```
-l, --lines            print the newline counts
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for missing the obvious! Will accept the answer in 6 minutes when SO let me to do so. :)

Comment: No, just use the `c` option for grep.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` can count matching lines:

```
grep -c 'lion' file
```

Output:

```
2
```

Syntax:

`-c`: Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/lion/!d' file | sed '$=;d'
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed -n '/lion/p' file | sed -n '$='
```

N.B. if the file is empty or the first sed command finds nothing the result of the second sed command is blank.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/lion/ {a++} END {print a+0}'
2
```

But I would say that the best solution is the one posted by Cyros using `grep -c 'lion' file`

Comment: You need to make it `print a+0` to get 0 printed instead of a null string if the RE doesn't exist in the file.